# Wsapi data store filter issues

Tags: rally

I am having trouble to get my filter of a defect store working. I am trying to to get all the defect that are created after a specific date(  Release.ReleaseDate ).

```
_getFilters: function(startDate) {


    var dateFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
        property: 'CreationDate',
        operator: '>',
        value: startDate
    });

    console.log('startDate is: ', startDate); //Sat Aug 23 2014 02:59:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
    console.log(dateFilter.toString());
    return dateFilter;
},
```

With the above filter, I always get an empty result, even thought I have verified that there are indeed some defects that are created after the startDate.

Note: If I remove the filter in the store config, I do see a list of defects.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date has to be converted to ISO format. Assuming you got the `release` object:

```
var releaseStartDate = release.get('ReleaseStartDate');
var releaseStartDateISO = Rally.util.DateTime.toIsoString(releaseStartDate,true);
```

your filter will include this:

```
{
                property : 'CreationDate',
                operator : '>',
                value : releaseStartDateISO
}
```

A full example is in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/defects-created-during-release).

Comment: Thanks! This is much cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I need to 'reformat' the startDate to the following form before passing it to the filter.

YYYY-MM-DD